# Installing a program written in vba: changing office settings

Tags: vba, ms-word, installation

I want to make an installer for programs (games) written in VBA(Office Word).
The problem I need an answer for:
It obviosly uses macros. For these to run the user suppose to change the security settings of word. But I can’t hope that they are able to do that or willing to make that extra effort. So I was wondering if there was a way to do that with the installer. You know, ask them if they want to allow it, and then the program would change the setting of office that the game could run.
Does any of you know if that is possible and if it is what the program is that I should use that for?

Answer (score 0):

Macros cannot change the security level that allows macros to run, because 
1 if macros aren't allowed to run they don't run so they can't do anything 
and 
2  because otherwise bad people would do it without asking and steal all your money from your bank account whenever you opened a word document

However, if your installer is written in some other language it could possibly change the setting. if it was run with sufficiently elevated privileges. But you shouldn't do this for all word documents because bad people. Instead, set up a trusted location - a folder whose file's can run macros, and save your file there. That maintains security for general word documents while allowing your file to run.